# How can I count down healthbar hitpoint per second in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a car game when the car runs out the road, its healthbar will be decreased. But i want to slow down the decrease. How can I do it?
This is the current code.

```
for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (car.getPosY() < 450 || car.getPosY() > 500)
    {
        car.hitPoints = car.hitPoints - 1;
        // if (car.hitPoints <= 0) car.active = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'll need `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds`

Comment: Why is there a loop for repeating the process of reducing health? If you want to reduce the health by a factor of 20, just remove the outer loop, and put the logic inside the condition as `car.hitpoints = car.hitpoints - 20`

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy Probably done to simulate the health slowly reducing, so you see how big the impact of the damage was. (Like in fighting games/RPG's), I do agree that using a for-loop isn't the right solution though.

Answer (score 0):

> But i want to slow down the decrease.

You will need to implement a timer for your car as follows: Whenever the car gets damaged, it has its health reduced and for a small time (say 1 second or 1000 ms) the car ignores all damage.

I have already questioned the use of the outer loop in the comments, so I won't dwell on that here. I am not using the loop as you have in your code.

Your `car` class needs to have a `int` variable for storing the time (in milliseconds) as shown

```cs
class Car
{
    int Timer=0;
    ...//Other stuff you have already
}
```

Next change your logic as shown:

```cs
if (car.getPosY() < 450 || car.getPosY() > 500)
{
    if(car.Timer==0) //This code happens once per second (according to the Timer value below)
    {
        car.hitPoints = car.hitPoints - 1;
        // if (car.hitPoints <= 0) car.active = false;
    }
    car.Timer += gameTime.ElaspedGameTime.Milliseconds;//Value of time (in milliseconds) elasped from the previous frame
    if(car.Timer >= 1000) //max value of time when damage is ignored. You can change this value as per your liking.
        car.Timer = 0; //Reset the timer
}
else car.Timer = 0; //Reset the timer
```

I typed this code without testing. Let me know if there are any issues.